# SAS type issue using a macro function

Tags: types, sas, sas-macro

I have a macro function defined as below.

```
%macro sqlloop(event_id, empl_nbr_var, fleet, base, position);
...lots of code...
%mend;
```

the actual code will be referencing based on a bigger table, but for troubleshooting and simplicity I have a shortened version of just the first row of this table, `row1`.

| event_id | empl_nbr_var | fleet | base | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 111 | 320 | CHS | A |

checking this in output data all of the types of Character except event_id, which is numeric. This is exactly what I want for the program. when I manually type in this, it works perfectly.

```
%sqlloop(1234, '111', '320', 'CHS', 'A');
```

however the following code throws all kinds of errors, stemming from what I think is a type issue.

```
data _null_;
    set Work.row1;
    call execute('%sqlloop(17,'||strip(empl_nbr_var)||','||strip(fleet)||','||strip(base)||','||strip(position)||');');
run;
```

*ignore the 17 part for now just assume thats correct*

The first error I get is below, and all other errors seem to stem from that table not being created.

```
ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: A, CHS.
```

note that there is no quotes around A or CHS, which I believe there should be? Still new to SAS so the not super familiar but to me it looks like that is the error. Is this something weird with strip(), or something else im missing entirely?

Comment: Turn on `OPTIONS MPRINT` and show the code the macro is executing.  You might need to double quote the resolution of `base` and `position` within the macro (i.e. `"&base"` and `"&position"` so that the code gen utilizes the parameters as string values.

Comment: that was it. thanks!!

Comment: Your manual call is adding single quotes into the values of the parameters.  The CALL EXECUTE() code is not adding those quote characters.  If you need the quotes in the values passed to the macro just replace `STRIP()` function calls with `QUOTE(TRIM())`  function instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [call execute inside a loop pulling from one table to execute a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67793195/call-execute-inside-a-loop-pulling-from-one-table-to-execute-a-macro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the macro processor everything is text.  So in your manual call you have included quotes in the values of the macro parameters.  And in the CALL EXECUTE() statement you did not.

You can either re-write the macro to not require the quotes in the values.  For example replace references like `&fleet.` with `"&fleet."`.

Or add the quote when generating the macro call.

```
data _null_;
  set work.row1;
  call execute(cats('%sqlloop(17,',quote(trim((empl_nbr_var))
                   ,',',quote(trim(fleet))
                   ,',',quote(trim(base))
                   ,',',quote(trim(position))
                   ,');'
  ));
run;
```

Comment: I went slightly similar with [`catx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67794728/1422451). Yes, the lovely, high learning curve of quote handling in SAS!

Comment: If you use the PUT statement to generate the macro calls to a text file then you can use the $QUOTE format to add the quotes.  `put ',' empl_nbr_var :$quote. ...`

Comment: @Tom should you add %NRSTR(%sqlloop( ?

Comment: Yes.  If the macro is complex it is critical to use %nrstr() to delay its execution until after the data step.  `call execute(cats('%nrstr(%sqlloop)(17,'...`